# Como declarar uma constante em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Como posso declarar uma constante em JavaScript? Procuro o equivalente (ao menos semanticamente) de

```
const int NUMERO_MAGICO=3;
```

em `C`.

Comment: há também em alguns styleguides o simples padrão:

var NUMERO_MAGICO = 3;

o google utiliza o mesmo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use o `const`. [Documentação na MDN do const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

### Sintaxe

> const name1 = value1 [, name2 = value2 [, name3 = value3 [, ... [, nameN = valueN]]]];

### Exemplo

```
const a = 7;
console.log("a is " + a + "."); // a is 7.
a = 3
console.log("a is " + a + "."); // a is 7.
```

Se tiver um navegador com suporte, pode fazer o teste. Mesmo que tente alterar uma variável definida com `const`, se tentar usar ela novamente ela manterá o valor anterior

### Compatibilidade

É suportado pela por versões mais novas da Engine Gecko (Firefox e afins), do V8 (Chrome), e também Internet Explorer 11. Safari 5.1.7 e Opera 12 aceitam `const`, porém permitem que o valor seja alterado mais tarde.

Editado: testei agora com NodeJS v0.10.20, que usa o V8, e funcionou como a documentação na MDN.

### Usar Javascript const em 2014?

Se pretende escrever uma aplicação para um grande publico, não vale a pena usar. Agora se é NodeJS ou um publico reduzido, creio que pode dar uma chance.

Comment: Ia falar sobre a compatibilidade, mas que bom que você editou e citou.

Comment: Confirmo que `const` funciona em IE11 e que o valor *não* pode ser alterado mais tarde.

Comment: jsfiddle para quem quiser testar no seu navegador: http://jsfiddle.net/WpcQm/

Comment: Outra pegadinha é que o `const` não-padrão da Mozilla não se comporta como o `const` que deverá existir no ES6 (que terá escopo de bloco, como com `let`).

Answer (score 14):

Não é possível se criar uma constante diretamente, mas pode-se declarar uma função que sempre retorna o mesmo valor:

```
function constante(valor) {
    return function() {
        return valor;
    }
}

var NUMERO_MAGICO = constante(3);

// uso:
var x = NUMERO_MAGICO();
```

Dessa forma, nada pode modificar o valor após criado. Mas **ainda é possível** se reatribuir `NUMERO_MAGICO` para outro valor ou constante:

```
var NUMERO_MAGICO = constante(42); // Funciona sem problemas
```

Há a proposta (no ECMAScript 6) de se introduzir a palavra-chave `const` ([como apontado por @Emerson Rocha Luiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6195/215)), mas no momento ela não é padronizada, nem suportada por todos os navegadores (também não sei quanto a JavaScript no lado servidor).

Por fim, há a possibilidade de se marcar [uma propriedade de um objeto como somente-leitura](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7757337/520779):

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "NUMERO_MAGICO", {
    value: 3,
    writable: false
});

var x = obj.NUMERO_MAGICO;
obj.NUMERO_MAGICO = 42; // Não tem efeito
console.log(obj.NUMERO_MAGICO); // 3
```

Entretanto, da mesma forma que no primeiro exemplo, ainda se pode reatribuir `obj`. Se quiser declarar um objeto para armazenar todas as suas constantes, pode tornar o objeto inteiro como somente-leitura através de [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze):

```
var constantes = { A: 10, B: 20, C:30 };
Object.freeze(constantes);
```

em vez de declarar cada propriedade daquele jeito, uma a uma. Apenas tome cuidado com a performance (como apontado nos comentários, ela pode ser bem pior que a de um objeto não congelado, dependendo da implementação).

**Observação:** independentemente do método escolhido, é bom lembrar que se sua constante for um objeto complexo, a referência para ele pode ser imutável mas ele não o ser necessariamente:

```
var OBJETO_MAGICO = constante({ "foo":"bar" });
OBJETO_MAGICO().foo = "baz"; // Funciona sem problemas
```

Para a questão de "como tornar um objeto complexo imutável", ver [essa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6213/215).

Comment: Parei e testei aqui com NodeJS instalado na minha máquina e funcionou. Eu pessoalmente não uso ele, mas talvez até passe a usar. Porém não me lembro se já faz alguma diferença quanto a melhoria de performance , embora o proposito de constante seja focado em realmente _ser constante_.

Comment: [Testei no ideone com Rhino](https://ideone.com/Baep2D), e também é suportado. Mesmo comportamento - a reatribuição falha silenciosamente.

Comment: Outro comentário pertinente sobre o `Object.freeze` que **só ocorre com V8**, inclusive recentes. Para alguns casos ele é muito, mas muito mais lento. Estava usando ele em NodeJS e abandonei ao ver que ficou pior. Aqui em detalhes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435080/any-performance-benefit-to-locking-down-javascript-objects

Answer (score 3):

Baseado na possibilidade de [propriedades de um objetos como somente-leitura](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757337/defining-read-only-properties-in-javascript) da [resposta de @mgibsonbr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6194/2998), e considerando correta a resposta de [@Emerson Rocha Luiz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/6195/2998), sobre o uso de [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const), só que ainda não suportado pela maioria dos browsers. Criei uma solução mais coerente e usual, para o cenário atual de uso (dos navegadores), que consiste no seguinte (acompanhe comentários):

```js
// ao invés de definir a propriedade read-only a um objeto qualquer,
// se define a propriedade read-only (suposta constante) ao objeto que as propriedades roots e globais são anexados.
Object.defineProperty(window, "NUMERO_MAGICO", {
  value: 3,
  writable: false
});

// assim pode-se utilizar o valor como um objeto global e constante
// sendo que a unica forma de redefini-lo ou exclui-lo é redefinindo o objeto window
var x = NUMERO_MAGICO;
NUMERO_MAGICO = 42; // Não tem efeito
document.body.innerHTML = NUMERO_MAGICO; // 3
```

Assim, sendo a forma mais próxima de se obter um comportamento similar a uma constante (com maior compatibilidade) em javascript.

**Compatibilidade:**

Testei nos seguintes browsers (utilizando [este jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fernandoleal/pptz7rxr/2/)):

```html
<table border="1" bordercolor="#ccc">
 <thead><tr><th>Navegador</th><th>Versão</th><th>Compativél</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>IE</td><td>11</td><td>Sim</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Maxthon</td><td>4.4</td><td>Sim</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Chrome Canary</td><td>43.0</td><td>Sim</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Opera beta (Next)</td><td>29.0</td><td>Sim</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Firefox</td><td>36.0</td><td>Sim</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Opera</td><td>28.0</td><td>Sim</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Safari</td><td>5.1.7</td><td>Sim</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

> (Teste em seus browsers e editem está listagem, para realmente
>       verificar a compatibilidade dessa solução);

Answer (score 2):

Nenhuma variável é sempre constante em javascript, porém você pode fazer o seguinte:

```js
var NUMERO_MAGICO = 3;
```

Sobre o `int` o javascript atribui automaticamente tipagem de acordo com o valor recebido na variável.

Comment: bem que poderia pelo menos alterar _Nada é sempre constante_ na sua resposta