# Como criar um objeto imutável em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, objetos, imutabilidade

Sei que é possível "congelar" um objeto em JavaScript através do método `Object.freeze`:

```
var x = { foo:"bar", complexo:[1,2,3] };
Object.freeze(x);
x.foo = "baz"; // Não tem efeito
console.log(x.foo); // bar
```

Entretanto, os objetos complexos dentro dele continuam mutáveis:

```
x.complexo[1] = 10;
console.log(x.complexo); // [1,10,3]
```

Como fazer para que o objeto inteiro se torne imutável?

Comment: Perfeito ter criado outra pergunta e respondido ela em vez de deixá-la perdida na resposta de variável constante em http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6190/2884. Com essa resposta aqui vai facilitar pra quem for usar o Google mais tarde

Comment: +1 bem bacana, a resposta é a mesma que eu faria, porém eu espero que pouca gente saia utilizando esse recurso, afinal eu já tenho minhas ressalvas quanto uso de constantes, imagina agora explicar pra alguém que não entende de escopo que ele deu um freeze num objeto que esta sendo utilizado e precisa ser manipulado em outro contexto porém pertencente ao mesmo escopo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Segundo [a documentação do `Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), não existe um método pronto para isso, é necessário se criar uma função especial para se iterar sobre os campos do objeto e aplicar `freeze` em cada um deles:

```
function deepFreeze (o) {
  var prop, propKey;
  Object.freeze(o); // Primeiro congela o objeto.
  for (propKey in o) {
    prop = o[propKey];
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(propKey) || !(typeof prop === "object") || Object.isFrozen(prop)) {
      // Se o objeto está no prototype, não é um objeto, ou já está congelado, pule.
      // Note que isso pode deixar uma referência não congelada em algum lugar no objeto
      // se já existe um objeto congelado contendo outro objeto não congelado.
      continue;
    }

    deepFreeze(prop); // Chama deepFreeze recursivamente.
  }
}
```

Exemplo do caso especial mencionado no código (para evitá-lo, comente a parte onde ele verifica se o objeto já está congelado para não congelá-lo de novo):

```
var raso = { foo:{ bar:"baz" } };
Object.freeze(raso); // { bar:"baz" } continua não congelado
var fundo = { raso:raso }
deepFreeze(fundo); // raso não é afetado, pois já estava congelado
fundo.raso.foo.bar = 42; // Atribui corretamente
```

É preciso entretanto ter cuidado especial com casos em que o objeto possui referências circulares. Isso não é um problema no código acima tal como está (uma vez que a checagem por "já congelado" evita que um mesmo objeto seja visitado duas vezes - e portanto evita um loop infinito), mas se torna um problema caso esse teste seja retirado.

Por fim, é bom mencionar que dependendo da implementação congelar um objeto pode impactar negativamente a performance (como citado [num comentário a uma pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6190/como-declarar-uma-constante-em-javascript/6194#comment10186_6194)) - ao contrário do que normalmente seria esperado, que essa imutabilidade trouxesse a possibilidade de otimizações que um objeto mutável não permite.

Answer (score 3):

A classe **Object** no ECMAScript 5 permite definir uma propriedade READ-ONLY num objeto arbitrário via o método **defineProperty** e com isso podemos criar objetos imutáveis em JavaScript, mas isso só funciona no Browsers mais modernos que implementam ES5 (IE9+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox e Opera).

```
var o1 = {}; // Cria um novo objeto

Object.defineProperty(o1, "a", {
    value : 37,
    writable : false // define a propriedade "a" como imutável
});

console.log(o1.a); // loga o valor 37 de "a"

// Nehum Error será lançado na tentativa 
    // de atualizar o valor (somente será lançado se 
    // usarmos o strict mode e neste caso será lançado
    // mesmo se o novo valor seja igual ao original.
o1.a = 25;
console.log(o1.a); // loga 37. A atribuição não tem efeito.
```

Nesta proposta a solução é por Design e deverá ser definida em tempo de Análise e mais adequada quando usando o pattern Immutable em JavaScript.

Uma tentativa de redefinir posteriormente no seu código  esta propriedade com o valor `writable: true` lançará um **TypeError**. Veja ilustração abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]