# Singleton em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, design-pattern, singleton

Como implementar o padrão Singleton em JavaScript de uma forma simples e correta - que me assegura que a instância será única?

Já vi implementações um tanto complexas, mas já não seria o suficiente algo assim?

```
var xyz = xyz || (function (){
    [..]
})();
```

O que ela teria de errado?

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você está buscando (acho que é por causa do exemplo; geralmente, simulacros de Singleton em JS usam `new`). Não sei se te ajuda, mas eu costumo recomendar usar um objeto literal em vez de tentar simular singletons. Resolve alguns casos de uso, provavelmente não todos.

Comment: Poisé, eu esqueci de comentar isso na pergunta. Se com os objetos literais globais, eu tenho necessidade de singleton.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

É impossível se criar um *singleton* em JavaScript, dada a natureza prototípica da linguagem. A grande maioria das linguagens orientadas por objeto usa o que chamamos de **OO Clássica**, em que classe herda de classe e objeto instancia classe:

```
classe A   <==   classe B (herda de A - sua "superclasse")
   ^                ^
   |                |
objeto 1         objeto 2 (não herda de objeto 2 - não diretamente, pelo menos)
```

Já na **OO Prototípica**, não existem classes, e objeto herda de objeto:

```
objeto 1   <==   objeto 2 (herda de objeto 1 - seu "protótipo")
```

JavaScript (em sua versão atual) tem semântica de protótipos, somente, mas uma sintaxe bizarra que faz *parecer* que ela implementa OO Clássica, quando na verdade isso não ocorre:

```
function A() { this.foo = 10; }
var objeto1 = new A();

function B() { this.bar = 20; }
B.prototype = new A(); // Vou chamar esse objeto de "anônimo"; poderia ser o próprio objeto1
var objeto2 = new B();
```

Parece que a "classe" B herdou de A, e os objetos "instanciaram a classe", certo? Mas o código acima poderia ser escrito igualmente da seguinte forma:

```
var objeto1 = { foo:10 };
var objeto2 = Object.create({ foo:10 }, { bar:{ value:20 } }); // anônimo poderia ser objeto1
```

Em ambos os casos, `anônimo` é o **protótipo** do `objeto2`. Isso significa que qualquer acesso de leitura tipo `objeto2.foo` irá primeiro ver se existe a propriedade `foo` em `objeto2` e, se não existir, retornará `anônimo.foo`. Já numa escrita, ele criará essa propriedade em `objeto2` se não existir (ou atualizará, se já existir). Você pode ler mais sobre como protótipos funcionam [nessa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/215).

A consequência disso, entretanto, é que se você tiver uma referência para um objeto nada impede que você crie um outro que herde [prototipicamente] dele:

```
var xyz = xyz || (function (){ // Essa função só será chamada uma única vez, garantidamente
    this.foo = function() { ... };
})();

var abc = Object.create(xyz, { bar:{ value:20 } }); // Mas agora abc herda de xyz
abc.foo(); // Chamou o método foo de xyz, usando abc como this!
```

Ainda que `xyz` seja [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6213/215), ou tenha "proibido extensões" via [`Object.preventExtensions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) ou [`Object.seal`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal), nada disso impede que ele seja herdado. Se existe um meio de marcar um objeto como "é proibido usá-lo como protótipo de outros objetos", eu não conheço. Só impedindo os outros de obterem uma referência pra ele...

Finalizando, caso não tenha ficado claro, criar um objeto "vazio" herdando de outro seria o mesmo que "criar outra instância de sua classe". Pois todos os métodos do primeiro estão disponíveis para serem chamados, e o novo objeto possui uma cópia de todas as suas propriedades - podendo alterá-las ou não. Se algum método do objeto antigo presume que ele sempre será chamado usando `xyz` como `this`, chamá-lo via `abc` vai violar essa premissa, podendo ter consequências negativas. Ou seja: não assuma que um objeto JavaScript seja garantidamente *singleton*.

Answer (score 4):

Se o que você quer com um singleton é ter um a instância única, realmente não precisa complicar muito. Mas sem ver um exemplo inteiro, não dá pra saber se o seu código exemplo está correto. Por exemplo, se `xyz` for uma variável local você vai criar uma instância nova o tempo inteiro.

```
function getSingleton(){
    //esse código sempre cria uma instância nova
    // é como se você tivesse escrito "var xyz = undefined || (function..."
    var xyz = xyz || (function (){
        [..]
    })();
}
```

Já se `xyz` for uma variável global, fica estranho a forma que você escreveu. Por que checar a presença de um `xyz` declarado anteriormente ao invés de inicializar direto?

```
var xyz = (function (){ ... }())
```

Resumindo, se o objectivo for ter uma instância única inicializada preguiçosamente, acho que o normal seria o `xyz` ser declarado num escopo diferente de onde ele é inicializado:

```
var xyz = null;
function getSingleton(){
    xyz = xyz || (function(){ ... }())
    return xyz
}
```

Finalmente, uma coisa pra você prestar atenção: quando você estiver escrevendo código que testa se uma variável global existe use `window.xyz` ou `typeof xyz !== "undefined"` porque tentar acessar diretamente uma variável global que não existe é um ReferenceError.

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que a motivação por trás de `var x = x || ...` é evitar que dois ou mais scripts criem a mesma variável. Eu vejo isso muito no código fonte do jQuery, por exemplo. Esse código assume, é claro, que ambos os scripts já tenham em consenso qual deve ser o valor da variável se ela estiver ausente (se um esperar uma coisa e o outro esperar outra, aí vai ter problema...)

Comment: Sim, var x = x || ... existe, mas nunca ví alguém usar isso pra fazer um singleton. Normalmente pra isso você quer um único múdulo responsável por criar a instância ao invés de um monte de módulos testando se ela já tem valor...

Comment: Concordo, me referi ao fato da função de instanciação só ser executada uma única vez (o que realmente ocorre, ainda que não caracterize totalmente o padrão *singleton*). Quanto a ter um único módulo responsável, isso é desejável sim, mas difícil de se conseguir [garantidamente] na prática (se você não é cuidadoso, acaba num caso de [*Dependency Hell*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)). Se sua página tem 10 scripts externos, e você não tem certeza se dois deles incluíram a mesma dependência comum, o padrão acima ajuda na "defesa em profundidade"... :P

Comment: Exatemente, @mgibsonbr. Foi esse o ponto que eu queria chegar com o exemplo `var x = x || ...`.