# jQuery, evento click duplicado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Vi aqui que **não** tem como fazer [singleton em javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40603/singleton-em-javascript).

Estou com um problema nesse sentindo, tenho a seguinte instrução:

```
$("#mSalvar").click(function(){
    man.bSalvarClick();
});
```

Isso gera um registro duplicado quando o usuário clica em carregar a pagina sem que esta esteja terminada, ou seja o usuário força e o script é carregado mais de uma vez, sendo assim a instrução desse evento é executada mais de uma vez, teria como fazer essa instrução executar apenas uma vez de forma garantida ?

**Edit:** Outro caso seria um botão consulta, onde eu tenho que deixar o botão sempre habilitado, só que quando o script esta duplicado ele faz **N** consultas ajax em vez de uma por click.

Conforme imagem abaixo eu dei apenas **1** click no botao e veja quantas vezes a consulta foi executada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faço a chamada do arquivo js desta maneira:

```
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>...
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild('jConsultaManifesto.js');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse arquivo que tem HTML e faz a chamada do .js é chamado através de um menu, que faz o .load() desse arquivo, só que tem uns usuários que não aguenta esperar a pagina carregar, então fica turbinando o clique no menu antes na pagina carregar e o script fica duplicado, não posso flegar o menu para o usúario não ficar clicando caso me perguntem.

Comment: Você pode desabilitar o botão depois do primeiro click. `$(this).prop('disabled', true)`.

Comment: @KaduAmaral já fiz um até um .hide(), o problema é que o script chama a função por já estar duplicado, ou seja ele da 1 clique na tela e o script como fica duplicado executa duas vezes a mesma instrução

Comment: O problema então não é no click, mas no carregamento do script, certo? Como está carregando o script?

Comment: @KaduAmaral eu dou um append no arquivo escrevo no final do html onde a pagina esta sendo carregada document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

Comment: Pode editar sua resposta adicionando esse código e um exemplo de conteúdo do `fileref`? É texto ou um elemento DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma função que carrega os *scripts* e verificar se o *script* já foi carregado:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.load', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    
    var script = $(this).data('script');
    var src = $(this).data('src');
    
    if ($('script[data-name="'+script+'"]').length == 0 ){
        
        $('head').append(
            $('<script />').attr('type', 'text/javascript')
            .attr('src', src)
            .attr('data-name', script)
        );
        
        console.log(script, 'carregado.')
        
    } else {
        console.log(script, 'já foi carregado' );
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-primary load" data-src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" data-script="bootstrap">Carregar Bootstrap</button>

<button class="btn btn-primary load" data-src="jConsultaManifesto.js" data-script="consulta-manifesto">Carregar Consulta Manifesto</button>
```

Comment: parece que assim resolve, vou testar com mais calma, tenho que ver a questão se o arquivo.js carregar outra pagina com as mesmas variaveis, será que duplicaria o evento? Tenho que fazer mais testes, assim que possível eu retorno, mais sua solução é uma excelente idéia, obrigado desde já

Comment: Adicionar funções para verificar se o elemento já foi carregado é uma solução mas isso vai te dar muita dor de cabeça depois, pois o problema é simples, existe duas chamadas do mesmo método, ou você esta carregando o mesmo scripts mais de uma vez, ou o jquery também esta sendo carregado mais de uma vez, se você não retirar esta duplicidade você, vai ter de faze uma verificação para cada método depois.

Answer (score 2):

Se entendi bem, seu programa carrega HTML e scripts dinamicamente para cada página que abre. Deve ser algo como um *Single Page Application*.

Bem, o primeiro passo é entender as estratégias que você pode adotar para carregar as páginas.

## Carregar tudo no início

Dependendo do tamanho e do uso do sistema, uma estratégia pode ser concatenar todos os HTMLs em um e todos os Scripts em um script único.

O tamanho final será maior, mas uma vez carregado, o sistema terá um tempo de resposta bem mais rápido.

Se essa estratégia for viável, você só precisa garantir que a inicialização do script será feita uma vez.

## Carregar sob demanda

Esta é a estratégia que você está adotando agora. Cada página acessada carrega seu próprio HTML e JavaScript.

O erro que você está cometendo, no entanto, é carregar o HTML e JavaScript a cada acesso. Você deve garantir que eles sejam reusados em acessos posteriores.

No caso do Script é fácil. Ao invés de adicionar manualmente ao DOM, crie uma função no script principal onde as páginas podem requerer um script específico.

Por exemplo, segue uma implementação bem rudimentar:

```
var scripts = {};
function require(pagina, src) {
    if (src in scripts) {
        //carregar script de "src"
        scripts[src] = true;
    }
}
```

## Use AMD

Melhor ainda, você pode usar [AMD](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) e acabar de vez com código duplicado. Aí o gerenciamento de scripts em módulos será totalmente gerenciado por uma biblioteca confiável e seguindo o padrão da web atualmente.

Note que AMD é um padrão que pode ter diferentes implementações.

Você pode fazer com que cada página seja um módulo AMD, por exemplo:

```
define('myModule', ['dep1', 'dep2'], function (dep1, dep2) {

    //Define the module value by returning a value.
    return function () {};
});
```

Então sempre que precisar acessar um módulo basta fazer assim:

```
var $ = require('jQuery');
var myModule = require('myModule');
```

O gerenciador AMD garante que o módulo será baixado e inicializado apenas uma vez.

## Acabe com páginas dinâmicas

Talvez seu HTML esteja sendo renderizado no servidor. Para uma aplicação responsiva, seria muito melhor deixar templates estáticos de HTML e fazer o *bind* de dados obtidos via chamadas Ajax a um endpoint REST.

Vantagens incluem:

- Melhor desempenho
- Menor quantidade de dados trafegados
- API do sistema mais consistente
- Evitar mais uma camada de tecnologia para gerar páginas dinâmicas, que sempre geral algum tipo de problema
- Escalabilidade grandemente facilitada

A desvantagem é que precisa tomar muito cuidado para não acabar com muito código complicado no JavaScript.

## Cuidado com os eventos

Colocar manipuladores de eventos diretamente nos elementos, ainda mais em páginas que podem carregar várias vezes é sempre um problema.

Uma alternativa é não fazer o bind diretamente no elemento, mas usar apropriadamente a função [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) do jQuery. Exemplo:

```
$('#main-content').on('click', '#btn-salvar', function() {...})
```

Antigamente se usava a função 'live' para adicionar eventos em elementos que ainda não estavam no DOM, mas agora usa-se a forma acima.

A ideia é que o evento será disparado sempre que qualquer botão com `id=btn-salvar` for clicado dentro de um elemento com `id=main-content`. Independente se o botão existe, será criado ou recriado dentro daquele elemento.

Comment: não conhecia esse AMD, vou dar uma estudada, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Isso provavelmente ocorre por um fluxo duplicado de sua aplicação.

A forma mais fácil de previnir o problema é remover as atribuições do evento, para garantir que ele não seja executado mais de uma vez, usando **unbind()**:

```
$("#mSalvar").unbind("click").click(function(){ // faça algo });
```

Sobre singletons, uma forma prática de implementar é criando uma classe estática e atribuindo a instância de um objeto a ela. Não é um singleton de fato, pois o javascript não irá tratar se o nome de seu singleton é único, mas na prática, funciona semelhante a um:

```
var SingletonCtrlCliente = {
     InstanciaSolitaria : null
 }

 $(function(){
      SingletonCtrlCliente.InstanciaSolitaria = new CtrlCliente();
 });

 function CtrlCliente(){
    // função pública
    this.facaAlgo = function(){

    }

    // função privada
    function definaEventoDeBotao(){

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente descobri que posso fazer o evento click parar de se propagar entre outras funções que também são chamadas através do mesmo evento seria assim:

```
$('seletor').click(function(evt){  evt.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
```

> http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Comment: Interessante não conhecia, coloque um exemplo como na documentação do jQuery para enriquecer a resposta. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simplesmente adicione uma trava, e deixe seu elemento desabilitado na interface:

```
var salvou = false;
$("#mSalvar").click(function(){
    if (salvou) {
       return;
    }

    man.bSalvarClick();
    $(this).prop( "disabled", true );
    salvou = true;
});
```

Comment: assim resolve, mas dai terei que criar uma variável flag para cada evento click do programa, será que não teria uma outra forma de garantir que o evento click seja único, sem ter que criar essas flags e depois ter que ficar verificando elas

Comment: não tinha testado com a consulta onde o botão precisa ficar habilitado, então retirei o voto, mas obrigado pelo esforço, se tiver outra ideia me avise, obrigado mais uma vez