# Como funcionam os objetos criados seguindo singleton?

Tags: javascript, design-pattern, singleton

Gostaria de entender como funcionam os objetos criados seguindo o design pattern singleton em javascript.

Minhas principais duvidas são referentes aos métodos e atributos desse objeto, onde e como cria-los e onde e como acessa-los.

Li alguns artigos até em inglês mas não compreendi muito bem a forma de usar corretamente o singleton.

Como exemplo tenho esse código:

> Fonte: [Dofactory - Singleton](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/singleton-design-pattern)

```
var Singleton = (function () {
    var instance;

    function createInstance() {
        var object = new Object("I am the instance");
        return object;
    }

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (!instance) {
                instance = createInstance();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();

function run() {

    var instance1 = Singleton.getInstance();
    var instance2 = Singleton.getInstance();

    alert("Same instance? " + (instance1 === instance2)); //retorna true 
}
```

Os objetos estão sendo instanciados na function `run`, minha duvida nisso seria, se quero adicionar um método `stop` e um atributo `status` para saber se esse objeto está em `run` ou `stop`, como devo fazer isso seguindo o design pattern `singleton`?

Referencia: 

[A Beginner’s Guide to Design Patterns](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/a-beginners-guide-to-design-patterns--net-12752)

[JavaScript Design Patterns: Singleton](http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/)

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40603/singleton-em-javascript

Comment: Olá, @Rodrigo. Suas dúvidas não estão claras o suficiente. Você falou que são referentes a tais coisas, mas quais exatamente são essas dúvidas? Talvez com exemplos fique mais claro.

Comment: @Pablo adicionei um exemplo e tentei explicar melhor minha dúvida, veja se está melhor agora

Comment: "Os objetos estão sendo instanciados" *o objeto*, não "os" - a ideia do *singleton* é justamente que só exista uma única instância. Esse exemplo usa *lazy instantiation*, mas também poderia não usar, criando o objeto diretamente. De todo modo, é a função `createInstance` que você tem que alterar, para modificar o seu objeto *singleton*. Em vez de `new Object("I am the instance")`, você coloca o que você quiser que seu objeto seja. E o padrão garante que ele será o mesmo objeto sempre que você usar `getInstance`. P.S. não entendi essa parte: "saber se esse objeto está em `run` ou `stop`"

Comment: @mgibsonbr seria só o valor do atributo status, acho que estou comecando a entender...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Talvez começar olhando para ponteiros de memória dê uma esclarecida.

Veja essa situação utilizando o NEW

```
var a = new Object('Some Object A');
var b = new Object('Some Object B');
```

Nesse código temos dois objetos criados em duas variáveis diferentes. Na memória de sua máquina, fica mais ou menos assim:

```
Código                   Memória
var a ---------------->  Posição 0000
var b ---------------->  Posição 0001
```

Ouse seja, duas cópias são criadas.

Se eu fizer o seguinte:

```
var c = b;
```

Nesse caso, `c === b`, porque:

```
Código                   Memória
var a ---------------->  Posição 0000
var b ---------------->  Posição 0001
var c ---------------->  Posição 0001
```

Note que tanto `b` e `c` apontam para a mesma área de memória, ou seja, o mesmo objeto.

Isso é um básico de como funciona, resumido.
Agora olhe no seu exemplo:

```
getInstance: function () {
  if (!instance) {
    instance = createInstance();
  }
  return instance;
}
```

Aqui você tá fazendo que se `instance` não existe, então cria uma instância. Logo, cada vez que você chamar `getInstance`, na primeira vez ele cria com NEW e nas outras apenas retorna o que já foi criado da primeira vez.

Colocando isso nos exemplos que citei:

```
var a = Singleton.getInstance();
var b = Singleton.getInstance();
var c = Singleton.getInstance();


Código                   Memória
var a ---------------->  Posição 0000
var b ---------------->  Posição 0000
var c ---------------->  Posição 0000
```

Em resumo, isso acontece porque só uma vez é criado e na outra, apenas uma referência para a instancia Singleton é retornada.

Espero que o textão tenha ajudado!!!

Comment: Parabéns, estou vendo o curso do Maximillian do Understanding TypeScript - 2020 Edition, e achando sensacional, e estou em Singletons & Private Constructors, e eu gostaria de saber se isto nos ajuda a não usar muita memória, claro, em casos pequenos não faz diferença.

Answer (score 0):

No seu exemplo, `Object` seria o objeto que você quer tornar um singleton.
Basta substituir (dado que você definiu seu objeto) e, se usar apenas o Singleton, você sempre terá apenas um exemplar do objeto.

Você deve criar os seus métodos `run` e `stop` dentro da definição desse objeto seu.

Para uma revisão de como isso é feito, dê uma olhada aqui: [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de visualizar é a seguinte.

Imagine que você tem uma classe de conexão com o banco de dados, e não quer criar um objeto novo na memória toda vez que você precisar acessar o banco de dados, então você usa o Singleton.

Isso vai garantir que se crie vários objetos para fazer uma coisa comum em várias partes do projeto.

Answer (score -2):

```
const miSingleton = (function () {
// instancia guarda a referencia singleton
let instancia;

function init () {

    function metodoPrivado () {
        console.log('Eu sou privado');
    };

    let varPrivada = 'Sou uma variable privada';
    let numeroRandomicoPrivado = Math.random();

    return {
        metodoPublico: function (params) {
            console.log('Sou um metodo público');
        },
        propiedadePublica:'Sou uma propiedade publica',
        obterNumeroRandomico: function () {
            return numeroRandomicoPrivado;
        }
    };
};

return {
    // Obtenha a instancia singleton se nao existe ou crie uma
    obterIntancia: function () {
        if (!instancia) {
            instancia = init();
        }
        return instancia;
    }
};
```

})();
const singleA = miSingleton.obterIntancia();
const singleB = miSingleton.obterIntancia();
console.log(singleA.obterNumeroRandomico() === singleB.obterNumeroRandomico()); // true
console.log(singleA.obterNumeroRandomico());
console.log(singleB.obterNumeroRandomico());