# Quando usar factory em classes abstratas?

Tags: lógica, dart, classes-abstratas, factory

Classes abstratas são classes que não podem ser instanciadas e sua implementação depende de outras classes, mas usando a palavra chave **factory** pode-se "instanciar" uma classe abstrata.

Então, como e quando se utilizar deste recurso?

Comment: factory Logger(String name) {
    return _cache.putIfAbsent(
        name, () => Logger._internal(name));
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você sabe que a classe abstrata não pode ser instanciada, mas ela pode ter um construtor desde que construa um objeto de uma classe concreta, e claro, o correto é que esse objeto seja de uma classe derivada dessa abstrata.

Então você pode usar a classe abstrata como forma de decidir o que fazer. Você pode ter uma classe padrão que seja criada na maioria dos casos ou pode ter uma escolha baseado-se em algum parâmetro ou alguma informação que pode ser pega globalmente.

Note que se o construtor fosse normal ela teria que gerar um objeto concreto derivado dela, é isso que construtores fazem, mas teria que devolver o tipo da classe abstrata, o que não é o desejado. O mecanismo permite retornar o tipo concreto.

É útil quando o código da aplicação não precisa saber quais são as classes filhas que pode usar. Então você que está fazendo a aplicação só precisa conhecer a classe geral e ela se vira pra te entregar o melhor objeto possível para a situação, provavelmente de acordo com configuração que você deu (que no fundo acaba expondo conhecimento mínimo do que existe). Dessa forma as classes filhas passam ser detalhes de implementação. E de fato a classe abstrata precisa ter conhecimento de quais classes filhas existem, ainda que indiretamente.

Não deixa de ser interessante, mas eu acho que usar herança para isso é errado na maioria das situações. Já que a classe deve conhecer as filhas e essas são muito parecidas com a classe mãe, então por que não só flexibilizar a classe mãe para ter comportamentos diferentes de acordo com algum parâmetro em seu próprio construtor?

Lembrando que toda filha criada obrigará mudar a mãe.

Eu acho que o motivo principal desse mecanismo ter sido criado é justamente o que está no comentário, é até exemplo da documentação, e retornar uma instância da própria classe com uma lógica um pouco mais complexa do que um construtor normal conseguiria.

O exemplo da documentação é um bom uso, já com classe abstrata, pram mim, é abuso. Pode usar, mas geralmente tem forma mais simples de fazer isso e é querer fazer a orientação a objeto ser usada onde ela tem zero benefício (note que eu não disse pouco).

Obviamente pode ter alguma exceção e encontrar um cenário realmente válido, mas provavelmente seria algo envolvendo reflexão, é muita complicação para ainda um ganho pequeno e ainda forçaria a aplicação saber algum detalhe de implementação, mesmo que não todo ele.

Outro bom exemplo é criar um [Singleton](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105514/101).

O motivo para usar está ali em cima na resposta, mas eu consideraria que não deve usar nesse caso. Se usar seria algo assim:

```
abstract class WidgetService {
    WidgetService _cached; 
    factory WidgetService(String type) {
        switch (type) {
            case 'a': return new ConcreteWidgetServiceA();
            case 'b': return new ConcreteWidgetServiceB();
            default: throw new ArgumentError("precisa de um nome válido");
        }
    }
    Widget getWidget();
    void saveWidget(Widget widget);
}

class ConcreteWidgetServiceA extends BaseWidgetService implements WidgetService {
    WidgetService();
    Widget getWidget() {
        // code to get widget here
    }
    void saveWidget(Widget widget) {
        // code to save widget here
    }
}

class ConcreteWidgetServiceB extends BaseWidgetService implements WidgetService {
    WidgetService();
    Widget getWidget() {
        // code to get widget here
    }
    void saveWidget(Widget widget) {
        // code to save widget here
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/FactoryAbstract.dart).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712095/221800).

Desta forma só precisa conhecer a classe `WidgetService` e que parâmetro passar para ela. Isso parece muito errado e desnecessário porque dá para criar um método estático normal que faça a [fábrica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/157466/101) e lide com isso se realmente precisar do dinamismo imposto por esse padrão, e novamente, indica que não deveria ter herança já que qualquer filha nova teria que mudar a classe mãe.

Reforço, pra tudo tem exceção, mas um mecanismo na linguagem não deveria lidar com casos raros e sim com casos que acontecem muito. Claro que tendo o mecanismo criará uma tendência de escrever código assim e não será tão raro, fazer algo ruim.

Answer (score 2):

> Classes abstratas são classes que não podem ser instanciadas

Correto. O que a caracteriza por definição do [Dart Language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes) é o fato de não poder ser instanciada.

> e sua implementação depende de outras classes,

Não completamente. Pode ser que apenas alguns métodos sejam abstratos também. Não é necessário que todos sejam. Essa classe também pode ter propriedades (atributos) sem nenhum problema. Uma sub-classe dessa classe abstrata só precisa fornecer a implementação dos métodos abstratos.

> mas usando a palavra chave factory pode-se "instanciar" uma classe abstrata.

Mais ou menos. Ela vai aparentar, para o efeito do código, ter sido instanciada, mas seu uso principal é para você poder ter maior controle sobre sua criação.
Isto é, por exemplo, você pode retornar uma instância de uma subclasse específica sempre (podendo aplicar o padrão de [singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton)). Você pode, dependendo do parâmetro que você passou ao `factory constructor`, escolher qual a subclasse adequada para ser instanciada.

> Então como e quando se utilizar deste recurso?

Quando fizer sentido para você. Se você precisa criar um singleton, ou se você precisar fazer um procedimento para descobrir qual sub-classe precisa ser instanciada são bons exemplos. Sintaticamente não existe nada além do que simplesmente aplicar ambos os conceitos simultaneamente:

```
abstract class numero {
 List<int> numerosEscolhidos = [];

  String nomePorExtensoDoNumero();  // Método abstrato.

  factory numero(double numero) {
      numerosEscolhidos.insert(numero);
      if (numero%2==0)
         return classePar(numero);
      return classeImpar(numero);
    }


}
```

Comment: Sua segunda afirmação não parece fazer sentido ou está errada.

Comment: Editei para melhor compreensão, conforme sugerido. Obrigado :)

Comment: A dependência continua existindo **sempre**.

Comment: Qual seria a dependência expecificamente? Pois não consigo ver

Comment: A "dependência" que ele se referiu foi relativa a palavra **depende** em sua pergunta, na frase: "e sua implementação depende de outras classes". Na minha resposta, eu deixo claro que embora essa dependência exista sempre, não é obrigado que toda a implementação esteja contida em outras classes. A classe abstrata pode conter sim alguma implementação própria como descrito [aqui](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#abstract-classes) (Abstract classes are useful for defining interfaces, often with some implementation.)

Comment: Não, sua resposta primeiro disse que nunca depende, agora diz que as vezes não depende, então não deixa claro que a dependência existe sempre. Na verdade fora isso que está errado o resto não quer dizer nada para isso, não foi perguntado se pode alguns métodos ter implementação e outros não, isso acabou gerando confusão.