# Como fazer um objeto constante em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, constantes

Como faço para declarar um objeto constante em JavaScript? Por exemplo:

```
/* meu código */
object_teste = {valor:5}

/* console navegador */
object_teste.valor=10;
console.log(object_teste.valor) // aqui ele me retorna 10 ao invés de 5
```

Como deixar esse valor constante? Como se fosse uma variável constante mas nesse caso um objeto.

Comment: Perguntas relacionadas: ["Como declarar uma constante em javascript?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6190/215) e ["Como criar um objeto imutável em JavaScript?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6213/215) (não estou certo se alguma delas é duplicata ou se são somente perguntas parecidas, então não vou votar pra fechar)

Comment: A pergunta é boa e as respostas também, mas para que você pretende usar o objeto congelado? Se possível, evite congelar objetos. Eles ficam mais [lentos](http://jsperf.com/performance-frozen-object), sem falar que `Object.freeze` não funciona no IE8.

Comment: para declarar uma variável use `var`: var object_teste = {valor:5}, no caso você setou novamente o objeto, se vc quer uma constante, Object.freeze(sua_variavel);

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creio que algo como `Object.freeze(object_teste);` resolva seu problema.

Esta função "congela" o objeto, o deixando imutável.

Creio que o script abaixo ajude com a recursividade no caso de precisar congelar sub objetos:

```
Object.prototype.recursiveFreeze = function() {

    for(var index in Object.freeze(this)) {

        if(typeof this[index] == 'object') {

            this.recursiveFreeze.call(Object.freeze(this[index]));

        }

    }

}

// Uso:

myObject.recursiveFreeze();
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, deu certo :)

Comment: @tchicotti, o freeze() não permite mudar os valores. O Diego está correto. `+1`

Comment: Note que se alguma propriedade for outro objeto, você precisa congelá-lo também, na unha.

Comment: @bfavaretto, bem observado, se for o seu caso uma função recursiva deve resolver Silvio.

Comment: @bfavaretto sim verdade vou ter que fazer isso.

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta com algo que creio que ajude.

Comment: Valeu mano, funcionou dahora.

Answer (score 5):

Pode usar o [**Object.freeze()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```
Object.freeze(object_teste);
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/d3L8D/)

Comment: Obrigado amigo, deu certo :)