# Por que é possível mudar valores constantes em arrays do JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, imutabilidade

Tendo o seguinte código:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];
console.log(arr);
arr.push(4);
console.log(arr);
arr.pop();
console.log(arr);
```

`arr` não deveria ser constante? E por isso não deveria aceitar o método `push()` e `pop()`? Afinal, se incluo ou excluo um elemento dessa *array* estou mudando o seu valor, logo ela não é constante. Ou estou entendendo errado o conceito de constante no JS?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [Como declarar uma constante em javascript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6190/18246)

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: [Como fazer um objeto constante em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9079/18246)

Comment: Não entendi o fechamento, nem a aceitação de fechamento já que a pergunta linkada não fala nada sobre array.

Comment: Uma constante apenas evita a sobrescrita/redeclaração da variável ou de seu valor. Isso não significa que esse valor é imutável, pois **apenas o identificador da variável que não pode sofrer alterações**. Se o conteúdo do identificador for um objeto ou um array, os parâmetros/valores desse objeto poderão ser alterados normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa entender a [diferença entre tipos por valor e tipos por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101). Em tipos por valor o conteúdo (valor) está na variável, em tipos por referência o conteúdo (valor) fica em outro local, e a variável tem apenas um ponteiro para esse local.

O `const` se refere a este valor do que seria uma variável (no caso fica sendo uma constante). Então o código não pode mudar o ponteiro ali armazenado, ou seja, você não pode pegar aquele identificador e apontar para um objeto diferente do apontado inicialmente.

O conteúdo do *array* não é constante, ou seja, o que tem no local de armazenamento pode ser alterado o quanto quiser.

Atualmente, até onde sei, não há como tornar os elementos dos *arrays* serem constantes (há truques para conseguir indiretamente semântica semelhante).

Você pode inclusive declarar uma variável e apontar para o mesmo objeto. E sendo uma variável, ela poderá apontar para outro objeto quando quiser, se desvinculando deste objeto que já tem uma referência constante.

Portanto a constância (imutabilidade seria um termo mais adequado, JS, como muitas linguagens, não prima pela terminologia mais correta) é externa ao objeto. Algumas linguagens permitem a "constância" interna.

Não confundir o valor associado ao identificador ao identificador em si. O identificador existe no código, é uma palavra. O valor existe na execução e está onde o código determinar de acordo com o especificado. O identificador não pode mesmo, afinal ele não existe, ou não importa, durante a execução (em JavaScript isto não é verdade para todos os identificadores, mas apenas para os casos onde o identificador é no fundo um valor, e se mudado criam enormes complicadores, na prática não deveria ser feito).

Answer (score 0):

Penso que, de um modo mais prático, a explicação é a seguinte:

Quando se diz que a palavra reservada `const` cria uma "variável" do tipo `constante`, ou seja, que tal variável não será ojeto de alteração pois tornou-se invariável ou imutável, na verdade, não foi a variável por completo que se tornou uma `constante`. Vejamos: a grosso modo, as variáveis (falo no caso do Javascript) podem ser compostas por três elementos/características: 1) Identificador (ou referência); 2) Tipo; 3) valor. Assim, vejamos os exemplos abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No primeiro recorte, foi criada uma variável com a palavra reservada `var`, o que a torna uma variável que pode ser alterada a qualquer tempo. Beleza. Já no segundo recorte, temos a declaração usando a palavra reservada `const`, para dizer o quê ao `parser` do Javascript? Eis a questão: O analisador do JS, ao encontrar o termo `const` coloca um flag de "imutabilidade" não no elemento [Valor] da `constante`, mas sim no elemento [Identificador]. Ou seja, declarar uma variável como `constante`, não significa, objetivamente, que seu `valor` será constante em todos os casos, e sim que sua `identificação` e consequentemente seu `tipo`, sempre serão imutáveis. Como isso é verdade? Simples: Veja os três exemplos abaixo (execute-os):

```js
const a = "Por que não posso mudar?"
const a = "Porque o tipo dessa constante é [String], e para alterar o tipo, precisaria REdeclarar a constante, o que é proibido!
```

```js
const a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a);

a[0] = 99;
console.log(a);
```

```js
const carro = {marca:"Volvo", modelo:"XC40"};
console.log(carro);

carro["marca"]="Land Rover";
carro["modelo"]="Range Rover Velar";
console.log(carro);
```

Olha só! o valor das constantes dos exemplos 2 e 3 foram alterados com sucesso! E então eu pergunto: uma `constante` é mesmo SEMPRE constante? Está provado que não. O `valor`, a depender do tipo, pode ser alterado. Especificamente, se uma `constante` é do tipo `Array`ou `Object`, então, os elementos desse `Array` ou os membros desse `Object` podem ser alterados, sem problema, pois isso não implica na REdeclaração da `constante` - o que fizemos foi declarar valores para tipos de `constantes` que permitem essa atitude.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O `flag`de que falei (que o analisador do Javascript coloca numa variável ao encontrar o termo `const`) é aplicado ao elemento [Identificador], que por tabela (e lógica), não permite também modificar o elemento [Tipo], já que eu só posso mudar o tipo, redeclarando a `constante`- o que não é necessário para os tipos `Array`e `Object`, dos quais eu modifico o valor diretamente, pois a atribuição de um novo valor, com o uso do sinal de `=` (igualdade) é aplicado diretamente no elemento valor.